# Mid-point of a line segment

Tags: geometry

I have the question "Find the coordinates of the mid-point of the line segment joining each pair of points
(-5/4, 2) and (-1, -3/5)
"
I wanted to know the different ways to solve this and could you please show your working so that I understand how to tackle these types of questions better thanks.

Comment: please show us your working first !!! Don't expect us to solve your homework problems for you.

Comment: ((-5/4 + -1) / 2 , (3 + -3/5) / 2)

Comment: i'm just not sure if this is the right way to solve the question.

Comment: Dan-- In your comment the 3 should be a 2 in second coordinate.

Comment: Dan--Now in the edited version there aren't two points anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is the aptly-named midpoint formula, written as $$\left( \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} \right) $$
While this may look complicated, it really just means taking the mean (average) of the $x$ coordinates and the $y$ coordinates.

To do the calculation, you'd do $$\frac{-\frac{5}{4} + -1}{2}$$ for the x-coordinate and $$\frac{2+-\frac{3}{5}}{2}$$ for the y-coordinate. This comes to $$-\frac{9}{4}*\frac{1}{2}$$ (remember multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ is the same as dividing by 2) which then gives $$-\frac{9}{8}$$ for the x-coordinate. You can do the y-coordinate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could i leave the answer as (-1.125, 0.72) rather than a fraction ? and is this final answer correct ?

Comment: Yes, you can leave it as a decimal. However, your y-coordinate doesn't seem to be quite right, try it again.

Comment: Is 0.7 correct ?

Comment: @DanKhan, yes, I believe so.

Comment: How do i do that ?

Comment: @DanKhan, by clicking the green checkmark near the top of my answer.